# Self connection via WCF netTCPBinding

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a windows application which hosts two services as `netTCPBinding` and also has some client dialogs.

one of the services is duplex. When i run two different instances of my software (one as server and one as client) there will be no problem.

However, when i run only one instance as server and client (in tandem), the duplex service does not work. The problem happens on `Subscribe()` method call. after timeout exception, `Subscribe()` method of host will be invoked.

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough information in your question to provide a detailed answer, and I'm not sure but I'll give it a try anyway.

I bet your problem lies in the reentrancy behavior: Just mark your service implementation with the following:

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant)]
```

This will allow incoming calls from the same endpoint while you're processing a request.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not because of the WCF. It was because of the StreamInsight. If you are using WCF based sinks in embedded StreamInsight scenarios note that the sink will not be generated until an event comes into your query. In my case, it was not possible to connect to sink at first before sending data to source.